# Using Google chart javascript library to create an illustration during a XSL-FO transformation

Tags: javascript, xslt, msxml, google-visualization

I would like to use Google chart javascript library to create illustrations during a XSL-FO transformation. I found some examples using the now deprecated Google static image chart API to display charts using `<fo:instream-foreign-object>`. Since the documentation says that the charts are displayed in SVG, I was wondering if it's possible to do the same with the javascript library using MSXML processor's  element.

I wrote a test stylesheet using the sample below:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      // Load the Visualization API and the corechart package.
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

      // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
      // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
      // draws it.
      function drawChart() {

        // Create the data table.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
        data.addRows([
          ['Mushrooms', 3],
          ['Onions', 1],
          ['Olives', 1],
          ['Zucchini', 1],
          ['Pepperoni', 2]
        ]);

        // Set chart options
        var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
                       'width':400,
                       'height':300};

        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

In my stylesheet I first define the `drawChart()` function inside the `gchart` namespace:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:gchart="https://developers.google.com/chart/" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0"> 

    <msxsl:script language="JScript" implements-prefix="gchart">        
        import https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js;    

        // Load the Visualization API and the corechart package.
            google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

        // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
        // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
        // draws it.
        function drawChart() {

        // Create the data table.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
        data.addRows([
        ['Mushrooms', 3],
        ['Onions', 1],
        ['Olives', 1],
        ['Zucchini', 1],
        ['Pepperoni', 2]
        ]);

        // Set chart options
        var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
        'width':400,
        'height':300};

        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
        }
    </msxsl:script>
```

Then I call `gchart:drawChart()` inside `<fo:instream-foreign-object>` hoping that it will return the SVG code.

```
    <xsl:template match="/">

    <fo:root font-size="12pt" font-family="Times, PmingLiu">

        <fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:simple-page-master page-height="297mm" page-width="210mm"
                margin="25mm 25mm 25mm 25mm" master-name="defaultMaster">
                <fo:region-body margin="0mm 0mm 0mm 0mm"/>
                <fo:region-before extent="0mm" />
                <fo:region-after extent="0mm" />
            </fo:simple-page-master>
        </fo:layout-master-set>


        <fo:page-sequence master-reference="defaultMaster">
            <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                <fo:instream-foreign-object>
                    <xsl:value-of select="gchart:drawChart()"/>
                </fo:instream-foreign-object>
            </fo:flow>
        </fo:page-sequence>

    </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The problem is that Microsoft JScript doesn't load the library: it issues an error when encountering the `import https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js`. How should I do?

Besides, do you think the draw() function will return the SVG code?

Comment: Which Javascript engine is supposed to support an `import` statement of that form? If you really use MSXML then it uses the Microsoft ActiveX JScript engine of which I have never heard that it supports any `import`. And even if you had a Javascript engine supporting `import` then the browser DOM use `new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'))` is certainly not supported by the Javascript enginge.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Sorry, I'm not familiar neither with MSXML or JavaScript. If import is not supported by Microsoft ActiveX JScript engine, is there another way I can use to load the library?

Comment: I am not aware of anything specific to the engine itself, normally you would use host specific ways like provided by WSH or by IE or ASP. And a library written for a web browser is usually not of any use in a different host environment.

Comment: You could do that with custom code and an embedded, headless browser. We have built such solutions using Anychart mostly because it takes an XML input to define the chart which is easier to make from the XML for dynamic charts. Surrounded that code with a web interface, post it the chart XML and get back the chart SVG. So yes its doable, with 10s of 1000s of lines of code to do it right.

Comment: Another way would be to read this and try and replicate. Using Node.js ... https://blog.davidpadbury.com/2010/10/03/using-nodejs-to-render-js-charts-on-server/

Comment: Or this using PhantomJS ... with Google Charts even ... https://github.com/pstephan1187/PhantomJS-Google-Charts

Comment: Thank you, @KevinBrown. Using Node.js seems to be a good solution, it's just that I don't see how the XSL processor can provide the data to Node.js.

Comment: XSLT 2.0 and POST? Or use your MSXL expertise and do a post?